# How do I setup Kodi to play using SM player

Tags: kodi, smplayer

I want to use Kodi just for organizing files but I want them to be played in [SM player](http://www.smplayer.info/)

There are articles but those generally need a good knowledge of code

Comment: "There are articles"...where? Afaik, smplayer is just a front-end of `mplayer` which is the key player in the game

Comment: http://kodi.wiki/view/External_players  mpv player would also work.